# Matlab, fimplicit, how to show a specified region on graph using an inequality

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using the fimplicit command to produce a graph, but I have a condition x+y<=1, and I want only that region of the graph to be shown.

Example: `f = @(x,y) x.^2 + y.^2 - 3; fimplicit(f,[-3 3 -2 2])`

If there is no such option within fimplicit, I am also open for the suggestions to modify the figure after plotting fimplicit. PS. Of course, my function is not the one above, it is much complicated, so I thought it would be useful to use a simple example here in this post. By the way, simply changing -3 and -2 to 0 and 3 and 2 to 1 won't work on my original function. Alternatively, what will work with my case is to paint the graph to white for the parts that I do not what to be visible such as x+y>=1, but I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if instead of anonymous function handle you use a usual function handle, you will have more control over the output values of that function. Create this function in a separate `.m` file:

```
function val = fun(x, y)
    val = x.^2 + y.^2 - 3;  
    val(x+y>1) = NaN;
end
```

and call it like that:

`fimplicit(@fun, [-3 3 -2 2])`

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem, using `patch` command.

I simply draw a polygon for the areas that I do not want to be visible, then select the fill colour as white. Below, I draw a triangle for the values where x+y is higher than 1, and fill them white.

```
v = [0 1; 1 0; 1 1]; 
f = [1 2 3]; 
patch('Faces',f,'Vertices',v,'FaceColor','white')
```